# Find a Label in a Parent Node and set properties like TextFill

Tags: javafx-8

I am able to set the properties of a label in JavaFX 8 as such:

```
label.setTextFill(Color.RED);
```

However, I am trying to locate a label node by ID in a FlowPane and then set the TextFill but I am only able to set properties of the node such as visibility, for example the following will change the visibility of the label:

```
FPane.getChildren().get(1).setVisible(false);
```

But the thing that stumps me is how to drill down further into the label node in order to set properties  such as TextFill.

Comment: If you're sure you know the element 1 of the children is a `Label`, then just downcast it to a `Label` and call `setTextFill` as before. (Though if you know that, I find it hard to see why you can't just keep a reference to it anyway.)

Comment: I would suggest the same as @James_D and on top of that: Using CSS is even better. If you node the `Node`s ID it is easy as pie to apply custom styles via CSS and change them during runtime.

Comment: Thanks @James_D keeping a reference was what I was looking for.  Thanks eckig, I'll take a look at using CSS.